# how to add to a many_to_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

How to add new readers to a magazine subscription?

Basically, I am using a many_to_many association - I have a readers model, a magazines model, and a magazines_readers join table.

```
create_table :magazines do |t|
t.string :title
t.datetime :created_at
t.datetime :updated_at
end
create_table :readers do |t|
t.string :name
t.datetime :created_at
t.datetime :updated_at
end
create_table :magazines_readers, :id => false do |t|
t.integer :magazine_id
t.integer :reader_id
end
```

Now, if I do something like:

```
magazine = Magazine.create(:title => "The Ruby Language Journal")
matz = Reader.find_by_name("Matz")
magazine.readers << matz
matz.magazines.size # => 1
```

I can add Matz to the magazine subscription, but how do I add matz to the subscription in rails in the view+controller?

In otherwords, in the console I can just append matz - but how is this done in the application? What would the code look like? Would it be in the create action etc...

Please help clear this up for me, thanks!

Comment: The code would be the same in your controller. Find the magazine by id or however, and push into `reader.magazines` collection. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many gives a full run down of methods available.

Answer (score 3):

**Model**

class Magazine < ActiveRecord::Base

```
   has_many :magazine_readers
   has_many :readers, through: :magazine_reader
```

end

class MagazineReader < ActiveRecord::Base

```
 belongs_to :magazine
 belongs_to :reader
```

end

class Reader < ActiveRecord::Base

```
 has_many :magazine_readers
 has_many :magazines, through: :magazine_reader
```

end

Answer (score 2):

your models should look like this

**magazine.rb**

```
class Magazine < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :magazine_readers
   has_many :readers, through: :magazine_reader
end
```

**reader.rb**

```
class Reader < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :magazine_readers
   has_many :magazines, through: :magazine_reader
end
```

**magazine_reader.rb** file which is your join table. In this you can add other attributes also

```
class MagazineReader < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :magazine
   belongs_to :reader
end
```

For further information you can refer this [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do:

```
class Magazine < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :readers
end

class Reader < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :magazines
end
```

More here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association